# Combine an Array of Object to new Array

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I have an Array of Objects that looks like this

```
[
  {
   "labNumber": 1,
   "sampleRepeats": [
    {"lab": "CORE","reason": "Equipment failure","count": 1}
   ]
 },
 {
   "labNumber": 2,
   "sampleRepeats": [
    {"lab": "CORE","reason": "Tecan150 failed","count": 2},
    {...could be more...}
   ]
 }
]
```

How would I go about merging it into only one Array that looks like this?

```
[
 {
  "labNumber": 1,
  "lab": "CORE",
  "reason": "Equipment failure",
  "count": 1
 },
 {
  "labNumber": 2,
  "lab": "CORE",
  "reason": "Tecan150 failed",
  "count": 2
 },
 {"labNumber": 2,...}
]
```

Comment: You can loop through each top level object, and for each key-value pair in the objects in the array, you can use `major_object[key] = value` to set the values

Comment: so, you take the single object in the `sampleRepeats` property and add it to the object that contains it - question for you - what if `sampleRepeats` has more than one item? I would start by ignoring the fact that you have the "outer" array, and concentrate on what you're actually trying to achieve, since the focus of your code needs to be on the objects inside the outer array - once you have that done, the  rest is a loop

Comment: @Bravo then it'll have another object with the same labnumber

Comment: you haven't shown how that would look in the output

Answer (score 1):

This will convert the data input, editing it directly. If you want to keep the original, make sure to [copy it](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/object/3-ways-to-copy-objects-in-javascript/) first. If there are multiple objects of extra data in the sampleRepeats list, all of them will be added.

```
function flatten(data) {
    // Get each object to flatten
    for (var majorObj of data) {
        // Get the objects to get the extra data from
        for (var extraData of majorObj.sampleRepeats) {
            // For each key-value pair in the extra data
            for (var key in extraData)
                majorObj[key] = extraData[key]; // Add the key-value pair to the main object
        }
        // Remove the extra data list
        delete majorObj.sampleRepeats;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will do exactly what you want - assuming there's only ever one entry in `sampleRepeats` - which I assume is the case as the questions doesn't show this could be the case

```js
const input = [{
    "labNumber": 1,
    "sampleRepeats": [{
      "lab": "CORE",
      "reason": "Equipment failure",
      "count": 1
    }]
  },
  {
    "labNumber": 2,
    "sampleRepeats": [{
      "lab": "CORE",
      "reason": "Tecan150 failed",
      "count": 2
    }]
  }
];
for (item of input) {
  Object.assign(item, item.sampleRepeats[0]);
  delete item.sampleRepeats;
}
console.log(input);
```